# FileExists works AssignFile does not for long paths with \\?\

Tags: delphi

As suggested by Microsoft[1] and other webpages I am adding the extra four characters `"\\?\"` in front of my path/file strings in Delphi. This allowed me to bypass the error I get with `FileExists` (meaning it can find the files correctly and return "True" instead of "False")

However the same string is passed to `Assign()` or `AssignFile()` it does not work correctly.

At this stage the file_name looks like this

`'\\?\C:\Users\xyz\xyz\xyz\ONELONGWORD\xyz\xyz\namer.abc'`

The errors I get are ;

with this snippet:

```
procedure xyz(file_name : string; var FID: TextFile;)
.....
.....
.....
assignfile(FID,file_name);
rewrite(FID); //
```

I get the Invalid Filename error on the `AssignFile` line.

With this snippet

```
procedure xyz(file_name : string; var FID: TextFile;)
.....
.....
.....
assign(FID,file_name);
rewrite(FID); //
```

I get the Inaccesible Value  error on the `rewrite` line.

Any idea how to fix this?

I am using Delphi 10.X

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#maximum-path-length-limitation

Comment: Stop using legacy file I/O and switch to streams and reader/writer classes. That's how to fix it.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using the ages-old `AssignFile()` and not something modern, like `TFileStream`, `TStream(Reader|Writer)`, `TFile`, etc?

Comment: This is a legacy code and switching means changing >2000 lines (first finding them of course) :=) and ensuring nothing is broken in the rest of the tool chain. But I can see that this is the only solution (moving away from 'assign's)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AssignFile has an hardcoded limit on the file name: 259 characters.

AssignFile is part of legacy file I/O of pascal since always. This has been replaced. Use `TFileStream` or similar. Also have a look at `TFile`, `TPath`, `TDirectory` and others in `System.IOUtils` unit.

Comment: That alone won't explain the behaviour reported. What would explain it would be if the rtl was opening the file with CreateFileA.

Comment: is it possible to do a workaround with ; SetCurrentDir(LONGPATH) --->AssignFile(shortname) --> writefile --> Go back to the previous directory

Comment: @user You can answer the question yourself. However if you manage to find all the places where you need to do this, you could just as easily fix the code properly. Also, current directory hacks aren't threadsafe.